# Having issues with getting Chosen.js to display in my Django template

Tags: django, jquery-chosen

I'm learning development and I'm using a linting tool with Atom called linter-jscs.  I have a simple javascript file defined as the following:

linter-jscs invalid line break

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#id_facilitydimselect').chosen();
  }
)
  ;
```

The linting tool shows the following:

[image]

Is this really an error that will cause my code not to work?  I can't seem to get rid of it.

I'm trying to use the following Django template to use the chosen javascript library, but it is not displaying correctly.  So, it's either due to my error below or something else i'm not getting.

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src= "{% static '/accounts/chosen.jquery.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src= "{% static '/accounts/security_chosen.js' %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/accounts/chosen.css' %}">
    <div>
     <em>Facility: </em>

     <select id_facilitydimselect="Choose a Facility..." class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="4">
       {% for facility in facilitydim %}
       <option value="{{facility.coid_name}}">{{facility.coid_name}}</option>
       {% endfor %}
     </select>
```

I know that Chosen is installed correctly using pip install django-chosen and I can see it in my GET statement in the console as shown below:

```
[08/Jan/2018 09:52:39] "GET /account/profile/ HTTP/1.1" 200 76624
[08/Jan/2018 09:52:39] "GET /static/accounts/security_chosen.js HTTP/1.1" 200 88
[08/Jan/2018 09:52:39] "GET /static/accounts/chosen.css HTTP/1.1" 200 11978
[08/Jan/2018 09:52:39] "GET /static/accounts/chosen.jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 47205
```

What is really the issue?

Comment: All those .js files have status code 404 (Not Found). Focus on fixing that.

Comment: If the files are in that location, what could be a reason i'm getting a not found?

Comment: You haven't set your static root path correctly or you haven't configured your server to redirect /static/ to appropriate directory.

Comment: Alright, i have my static root setup correctly now and i'm getting the updated console shown above, but my form isn't showing as chosen.

Comment: What is strange is my console is no longer showing the GET message.

Comment: Select is missing an id. jQuery assumes it's id_facilitydimselect and in the code you pasted, select doesn't have an id.

Comment: I corrected that at an earlier time, i updated the latest template code.  Should my console be showing the GET?  It no longer shows status 200 like it did the one time.  If i change the path i get the 400, but once i fix it, it no longer shows the 200.  I did notice that a /js file is being created in my root directory with the security_chosen.js file duplicated there.

Comment: 2xx and 3xx status code are generally alright. In your code `id_facilitydimselect` is added as select attribute(`id_facilitydimselect="Choose a Facility..."` doesn't make any sense). You have to add it within an id attribute: `id="id_facilitydimselect"`

Comment: This worked, thank you for all your help Borut!  If you write up a solution i'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your js/jquery code is ok, but you have to add id attribute to your select input.

```
<select id="id_facilitydimselect" class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="4">
   {% for facility in facilitydim %}
   <option value="{{facility.coid_name}}">{{facility.coid_name}}</option>
   {% endfor %}
</select>
```

When working with jQuery, getting selector right is in 99 % cases absolutely crucial. Most commonly used are:

[id selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) that selects an element with a certain id value:

```
$("#id_value")
```

[attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) that selects elements with a certain attribute name/value combination

```
$("[attribute='value']")
// for example selector that selects elements with attribute name="test"
$("[name='test'])
```

[attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) that selects elements where attribute contains certain value

```
$("[attribute*='value']")
// for example selector that selects element where attribute name contains 'est'
$("[name*='est']);
```

[:input selector](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) which selects all input, textarea, select and button elements (all form controls)

```
$(":input") // selects all inputs
$("form") // selects form
```